# sql query group by not working in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query based on 2 IDs in the same table, the results of the sum have come out correctly, but the problem is group by cannot handle data that appears 2 times

```
SELECT coa_a.debet_april,coa_a.namacoaapril, coa_b.kredit_april ,coa_b.namacoaapril
 FROM `t_jurnalumum` join coa on coa.m_coa_4_id=t_jurnalumum.IdDebet 
 join (select DISTINCT m_coa_4_id, sum(a.Nilai) as debet_april, coa.namacoa as namacoaapril 
        from t_jurnalumum a j
        join coa on a.IdDebet=coa.m_coa_4_id 
        where year (a.Tanggal)=2021 and month (a.Tanggal)=4 
        GROUP by a.IdDebet ) as coa_a on coa_a.m_coa_4_id=t_jurnalumum.IdDebet 
 join (select DISTINCT m_coa_4_id, sum(b.Nilai) as kredit_april, coa.namacoa as namacoaapril 
         from t_jurnalumum b 
         join coa on b.IdKredit=coa.m_coa_4_id 
        where year (b.Tanggal)=2021 and month (b.Tanggal)=4 
        GROUP by b.IdKredit ) as coa_b on coa_b.m_coa_4_id=t_jurnalumum.IdKredit 
 GROUP by coa_b.namacoaapril, coa_a.namacoaapril
```

this the result
[image: here the result]

and this is the main table
[image: and this is the main table]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using the same table. The first sub query of join will give you the distinct value from first group by and second group by gives distinct value. And at the end you also have grouped the whole result. The first one gives two distinct value and second one gives two distinct value which eventually gives all value.

Comment: can you fix my query ? or something advice to make my query work correctly ?